# Run Matlab executable file with MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR)

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I would like to run a file that has been made executable for LINUX platforms through Matalb2013a.

The program requires that user install the MATLAB runtime libraries so I've downloaded the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) for the release 2013a.

I've installed it and I've added the path both to LD_LIBRARY_PATH and to XAPPLRESDIR how suggested during install.

However when I Run

```
sh run_PROGRAM.sh /usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81 
/INPUT_FILE/HG00096.chr21.txt /INPUT_FILE/FinalHG00096.chr21.samjustMut.sam
```

it returns

```
Setting up environment variables
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is .:/usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/runtime/glnxa64:
/usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/bin/glnxa64:
/usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/os/glnxa64:
/usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:  
/usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:
/usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/client:
/usr/local/MATLAB2013a/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v81/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64
run_PROGRAM.sh: 1: eval: ./PROGRAM: Permission denied
```

What does it means?
Where I'm wrong?
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Try to do the following....

`sudo chown your_linux_username:your_linux_username the_executable_matlab_file`

then

`chmod +x the_executable_matlab_file`

What we are doing here is basically changing the user and group permissions of that particular program to belong to you and in the next step we are letting linux know that this particular program is actually allowed to run as an executable.

If this still does not work then paste the result of the following command:

`ls -lah | grep the_executable_maltab_file`

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that you don't have rights to run PROGRAM.
What is the output of the command:

```
ls -l PROGRAM
```

?

Maybe you've compiled this program as a root? Try to change the access using [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod).